# KS two sample test, p-value equal to 1

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have done a KS two sample test with the following samples:
[image]

I have received a P-value of 1, I was expecting a high p-value but I thought this value can never reach 1 unless both samples are exactly the same.

Is this normal?

Comment: `I thought this value can never reach 1 unless both samples are exactly the same` -> not true.

Comment: Could you elaborate it more? Teach me please.